# neo4j clean install doesnt recognize 'using', 'load' at import

Tags: csv, upload, neo4j

I just installed neo4j 2.1.3 (the current latest release) on a mac. I started up the server via `bin neo4j start` and I can verify via `localhost:7474` that neo4j is running. I then continued to the neo4j shell with the following code:

```
➜  bin  neo4j-shell
Welcome to the Neo4j Shell! Enter 'help' for a list of commands
NOTE: Remote Neo4j graph database service 'shell' at port 1337

neo4j-sh (?)$ MATCH (n)
> OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()
> DELETE n,r;
+--------------------------------------------+
| No data returned, and nothing was changed. |
+--------------------------------------------+
8946 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$ CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (w:Word) ASSERT w.value IS UNIQUE;
+--------------------------------------------+
| No data returned, and nothing was changed. |
+--------------------------------------------+
131 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$ USING PERIODIC COMMIT
Unknown command 'using'
neo4j-sh (?)$ LOAD CSV FROM
Unknown command 'load'
neo4j-sh (?)$ "file:/Users/code/Downloads/w2.txt" AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'
Unknown command '"file:/users/code/downloads/w2.txt"'
neo4j-sh (?)$ MERGE (w1:Word { value: line[1] })
> MERGE (w2:Word { value: line[2] })
> CREATE (w1)-[:LINK { value : toInt(line[0])} ]->(w2);
SyntaxException: line not defined (line 1, column 25)
"MERGE (w1:Word { value: line[1] })"
```

I am trying to create a graph of bigrams, the csv file contains a list of words. I first delete the current data such that I can create a clean database from a .csv file. This works. I then create a constraint such that all the words are unique. So far, so good.

But then for the import it doesn't seem to recognise commands that are clearly defined in the [docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-load-csv.html).

What am I doing wrong?

**---Edit 1---**

I think there might be something wrong internally. Even when I copy code from the (docs)[http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypherdoc-importing-csv-files-with-cypher.html], it will give me erros.

*Code*

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.1.3/csv/import/persons.csv" AS csvLine
CREATE (p:Person { id: toInt(csvLine.id), name: csvLine.name })
```

*Error*

```
➜  neo4j-v2.1.3  ./bin/neo4j-shell
Welcome to the Neo4j Shell! Enter 'help' for a list of commands
NOTE: Remote Neo4j graph database service 'shell' at port 1337

neo4j-sh (?)$ LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.1.3/csv/import/persons.csv" AS csvLine
Unknown command 'load'
neo4j-sh (?)$ CREATE (p:Person { id: toInt(csvLine.id), name: csvLine.name })
> ;
SyntaxException: Unknown function 'toInt' (line 1, column 24)
"CREATE (p:Person { id: toInt(csvLine.id), name: csvLine.name })"
```

**---Edit 2---**

The previous error prompted me for a new fresh install which revealed something even more strange. This script now runs properly in `neo4j-shell`;

```
MATCH (n)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()
DELETE n,r;

CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (w:Word) ASSERT w.value IS UNIQUE;
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV FROM
  "file:/Users/code/Downloads/w2.txt"
  AS line
  FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'
MERGE (w1:Word { value: toString(line[1]) })
MERGE (w2:Word { value: toString(line[2]) })
CREATE (w1)-[:LINK { value : toInt(line[0])} ]->(w2);
```

But when it has completed running I find that the neo4j server has shut down/crashed. When I `neo4j start` or `neo4j restart` the server then I get the same errors again as before.

**final edit**

Turns out that `$ neo4j` starts up a neo4j version but that previously deleted. A hint for others, always make sure you use `$ bin/neo4j start` and `$ bin/neo4j-shell` from the install folder. Don't assume `$ neo4j start` or `$ neo4j-shell` to always work. What went wrong here is that I started a wrong server version but a right shell version. These two could not communicate nicely with eachother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it is kind of a version issue? I.e. do you have an older version of Neo4j installed? 
Perhaps it messes up the paths? Try to clean out all your neo4j installations (search for filenames with neo4j on your disk) and try to start over?

Also check that there are no launch-daemon scripts for Neo4j anymore.

How do you determine that your server has crashed for the second script? Perhaps also check the logfiles in data/log/* and data/graph.db/messages.log

Comment: i make sure no other java process is running through ```ps -a``` and then using the ```kill``` command for any java process before i run neo4j. the downloaded folders are thrown away and refreshed via new download. the server crash is discovered because the neo4j-shell gives a connection error and the ```neo4j status``` command is telling me that the server is down.

Comment: it was a version issue but it was hidden! turns out that ```$ neo4j``` starts up a neo4j version on my system but not the one i want. a hint for others, always make sure you use ```$ bin/neo4j start``` and ```$ bin/neo4j-shell``` from the install folder instead of ```$ neo4j start``` or ```neo4j-shell```.

Answer (score 0):

You should or Begin your transaction (see e.g. here : http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/shell-commands.html#_example_dump_scripts

Or create an Import .cql file with your statements and specify that file when running the shell .

For e.g a import.cql file :

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Node) assert n.id IS UNIQUE;
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM FILE "file:///path-to-your-file" AS csv
CREATE (n:Node {id:toInt(csv.id)})
```

Then execute the import.cql statements with the shell :

```
// This assumes that the import.cql file is located in your Neo4j install dir
./bin/neo4j-shell -file import.cql
```

Here a result that a I just executed on a running test DB :

```
absoluttly:graphdb ikwattro$ ./bin/neo4j-shell -file import.cql
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Constraints added: 1
200 ms
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes created: 1
Properties set: 1
Labels added: 1
41 ms
```

Here are some useful links :

http://www.neo4j.org/graphgist?d788e117129c3730a042
http://jexp.de/blog/2014/06/using-load-csv-to-import-git-history-into-neo4j/

Comment: no dice. ➜  neo4j-v2.1.3  ./bin/neo4j-shell -file import.cql
and the steps you've shown me gives me: ERROR (-v for expanded information): Unknown command 'using'. still the same error.

Comment: also if i read you link about dump scripts correctly: that does not refer to uploading data via csv but via cypher. so that would not apply here i think.

Comment: Well from the Load CSV part of the Doc : "To import data from a CSV file into Neo4j, you can use LOAD CSV to get the data into your query. Then you write it to your database using the normal updating clauses of Cypher." http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-load-csv.html#load-csv-import-data-from-a-csv-file

Comment: Check the edits. I think the solution are proposing isn't solving the mysterious problem I am having.

Comment: If your csv file is no data sensitive, can you please provide a partial dump in a gist file ?

Comment: the datafile just contain 1000000 bigrams. small snippet: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6c1f4a8570febcb05978, full dataset: http://www.ngrams.info. i think the problem is related to the fact that i am adding a lot of data, not so much the structure of the data. the .txt file is 17MB.